# Retrieving emails from gmail

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0

I've been using Oauth for G-mail to get the emails, it's going perfectly until I faced a problem that after following the [Goggle playground for Oauth](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/)
the last response contained the emails as I want except than that I want the **Full** content of the email, not only the *summery* ...
what I'm missing ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example flow there is for using an [unread messages feed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) with an aggregator/RSS-reader software. Google has decided to only include the summary and a URL to view the message on the Gmail website there.

If you want download the message contents you have to fetch them using IMAP. Google also supports [IMAP using OAuth authentication](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview).